# Codeigniter - change status of task if it's expired

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a range of cases that when opened, display a list of tasks. All of these tasks that have a status assigned to it: Ongoing, Completed and Overdue. There is an expiration date set to each task. I would like to try and change the status of the task to overdue when the page loads if the task is past the expiration date.

I want to check when the page loads if the task has expired, and if so, change the status of that task to overdue.

The data I am getting from my query is below

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1 [agency_association_ID] => 1 [task_ID] => 3 [assigned_user_ID] => 8 [status] => Ongoing [comments] => Test task [date] => 2013-04-12 [task] => Domestic violence [active] => 1 ) )
```

VIEW

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
if($date > $tasks->date) 
{ 
    echo"OVERDUE"; 
}
else 
{ 
    echo"IN DATE"; 
}
```

I don't want to do a check in the controller in case it checks every time it loads and gets stuck in a continuous loop

Comment: Try date checking in your sql query.

Comment: I tried that just after I posted this and it worked, hurrah! Cheers